# What is the meaning of "each" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Teams qualified from the ECPC qualification round on 19 October will need to pay an extra 200 LE each (to be collected onsite after the qualification)

Does this mean each member of the team has to pay 200 LE or the whole team has to pay 200 LE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "each" when used with a plural noun such as "teams" implies once per team.  So it should be an additional 200 LE per team.

At least this is my understanding.  If they wanted to say that each individual on the team has to pay an additional 200 LE, they would likely say it as I've written it here, so:

> Individuals of teams qualified from the ECPC qualification round on 19
>   October will need to pay an extra 200 LE each (to be collected onsite
>   after the qualification)